# How should I write a Query with "Group By Clause" to get following specified output?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have written a Query in MSBI Query Editor as follows,

```
SELECT 
DATEPART(year,tblReservation.Date) AS "Year",
tblReservation.Room AS "Room No.",
COUNT(tblReservation.Room) AS "No. Of Times", 

CASE 
WHEN PaidFor = 1 
THEN 
COUNT(tblReservation.Room)*tblPrice.Price 
ELSE 0 
END AS "ActualRevenue",

COUNT(tblReservation.Room)*tblPrice.Price AS "TargetRevenue"

FROM tblReservation INNER JOIN tblRoom 
ON tblReservation.Room = tblRoom.RoomNumber 
INNER JOIN
tblPrice ON tblRoom.PriceID = tblPrice.PriceID

GROUP BY tblReservation.Room, tblPrice.Price,
tblReservation.PaidFor, DATEPART(year,tblReservation.Date)
```

This Query is showing me output like this(Matrix Layout MSBI),

[image: Matrix Layout]

My Query output is as,

[image: Query Output]

My Report design layout is,

[image]

What I want is, in my Matrix layout, the room no. 100 is two times, for year 1999 & 2013.
It is occupying two rows. I want this in one row in my Matrix layout.
How should I do ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample Dataset with a few rows, i.e. some typical output from your query?

Comment: Hi. I have also specified my Query Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what's going on with your matrix without more details, but this should all work fine without any special effort.

Take a subset of your data:

[image]

Create a standard matrix, adding a few extra columns to to the column group:

[image]

You can see the row group is based off `RoomNo` and the column group is based off `Year`. The data cells are just aggregated values. This works as expected for room 100:

[image]

Without more detail it's impossible to tell what's causing your issue, but the above shows this is certainly possible with everything as standard.

In your case I would try:

1. Checking the row groups details and see if it is grouped on anything other than `RoomNo`; same for the column group and `Year`.
2. Create a new text matrix from scratch with the above grouping and see if this new item is working as expected.

Comment: Hi lan. I did the same grouping as you did in the pic. But not getting ,why it is taking two rows for the Room no. 100. Please check my design layout above. Please, also check my Query.